# How to show uploaded image url in custom tab in admin grid in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-images, custom-admin-grid

I want to show the uploaded image URL in a custom tab in admin grid in Magento 2.
 In the custom tab, image name is coming from the database.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

As shown in the picture I want to show that image URL in that form

Comment: Do you mean, you want to show that Image URL into custom tab detail section?

Comment: yes as picture above there i want to show image URL uploaded by customer in form

Comment: @AshishRamchandani are u looking for https://prnt.sc/n8wt1w like this?